# Can dimensionless structures form dimensional structures?

Tags: geometry

I've been thinking about the definition of graphic elements, such as points, lines, areas, and so on ... Just as a level 2 or 3 dimension (d = 2 or d = 3) must respect principles already shown, larger dimensions (d> = 4) as well. One is about how they are formed. That is, a line is formed by infinite points, whereas, an area, is formed by infinite lines, volume, by infinite areas ... However, I wondered how a dimensionless structure (in this case the point), can form a structure dimensional (line) even though it does not have a value for this object. That is, an area can be defined as a * b (product of two lines), or a + a + a + ... + a (b times). So, as a point, without dimension, can I get a line? Of course, the idea does not assign any value, not even 0, to the point, since any value becomes a segment of the line, that is, it has a dimension. I think it is closely linked to the idea of ​​infinite, that is, infinitely small. I would like some information and, if possible, where I can find it, an article, book, among others. Grateful!

Comment: A point is not dimensionless. It has dimension $0$.